# How can I connect to a Lotus Notes database (*.nsf) with Perl and DBI?

Tags: perl, odbc, lotus-notes

I've got a Perl/DBI program that needs to connect to a Lotus Notes database.  With NotesSQL installed, the program works, but keeps prompting me for a Notes password.  Is there any way to pass the Notes ID and password programmatically? I'm using ActiveState Perl 5.8.8, Notes 8.5, and NotesSQL 8.0.

Comment: ahh I wish Lotus Notes would just fold already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [DBI->connect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#connect):

> ```
> $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
>         or die $DBI::errstr;
> ```

or

> ```
> $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password, \%attr)
>         or die $DBI::errstr;
> ```